# Code_39 in iOS PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm having the issue where my Android devices are able to scan rather long barcodes (CODE_39), even from quite a distance, but iOS devices aren't.

I'm building my app through the Phonegap Build API, with the following line in config.xml:

Please follow this [link](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/34)